# Error filtering template: Notice: getimagesize(): Read error!

Tags: magento2, magento-2.0

Error filtering template: Notice: getimagesize(): Read error! in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/local.devsite.com/web/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Product/Image.php on line 949

I get this on my Homepage and any page with Products.

I see that this issue was said to be resolved in 2.0
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/2276

How am I still getting this error?

Comment: May be check for Image Path. It's Proper or not

Answer (score 4):

This could happen on the images with 0 size. Run this command on your pub folder to find possible images with 0 size and delete them:

`find . -size 0`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting because of placeholder is not available on your Magento setup website. Please upload placeholder image using following steps.

```
> Go to admin panel
> Go to Store > Configuration
> Click on Catalog
> Click on Product Image Placeholders tab on the right side
> Upload placeholder on Base, Small, Swatch image & thumbnail.
```

It will resolved this issue.

Comment: I tried your solution its not working for me